# What does class ClassName<int>{} means in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, oop

```
class MyBloc extends Bloc<MyEvent, MyState> {
  MyBloc() : super(StateA()) {
    on<EventA>((event, emit) => emit(StateA()));
    on<EventB>((event, emit) => emit(StateB()));
  }
}
```

How Bloc use `<MyEvent, MyState>` under the hood?

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are searching for generics. Here is a good starting point:

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generics